# How to find covariance of sample mean and sample standard deviation

Tags: probability, correlation, covariance

I have a question to find the covariance of sample mean and sample standard deviation based on the following:
[image]

I have tried something on my scratch paper, but for some reason, I cannot upload on here. so please anyone help me, Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Maybe try again, normally it should be uploadable I guess, or do you need 10 reputation for that? Anyway, upvoted, maybe it is a reputation related issue. One more upvote and you have 10 reputation.

Comment: I hope someone could help me